# Unable to login to Google account after reflashing gapps (LineageOS 14.1)

Tags: google-account, google, logging

today I ran into some trouble and had to reflash my LineageOS system and with that my GApps. After reflashing (dirty flash, by the way) I could not login to my Google account anymore. After logging in, I was just brought back to my previous screen and the Google account was not added. I can see my device show up on https://myaccount.google.com/. I've collected a logcat of what errors were being spit out when trying to log in. I hope anyone can help me with this! I have already tried turning off 2FA and even tried deleting the `/system/etc/hosts` file as [this](https://androidforums.com/threads/cannot-sign-in-to-google-account-after-trying-everything.653993/#post-5912159) forum post recommended.

```
01-21 20:22:50.104  8412  8412 E Finsky  : [1] com.google.android.finsky.tos.TosAckedReceiver.a(10): Could not get DFE API, returning.
01-21 20:22:51.057 12771 12771 E ResourceType: Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010575
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices: [AuditHelper] Error getting account ID
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices: guc: BadAuthentication
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at gtq.a(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):15)
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at gtp.a(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):2)
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at gtp.c(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):6)
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at gtp.b(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):1)
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at gtp.b(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):3)
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at gtp.f(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232))
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at anrn.run(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232))
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at qzy.run(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):3)
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at rgd.run(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232))
01-21 20:22:52.208 12771 14287 E SetupServices:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices: [GoogleServicesActivity] Exception writing audit records
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices: guc: BadAuthentication
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at gtq.a(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):15)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at gtp.a(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):2)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at gtp.c(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):6)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at gtp.b(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):1)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at gtp.b(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):3)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at gtp.f(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232))
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at anrn.run(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232))
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at qzy.run(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232):3)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at rgd.run(:com.google.android.gms@14847017@14.8.47 (040306-228741232))
01-21 20:22:52.214 12771 12771 E SetupServices:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```